# How can I secure a FTP transfer using like an SFTP middleman

Tags: security, ftp, sftp

I have a little home security camera that has FTP capabilities to upload captured videos/images to an FTP server.

The only thing is I use a droplet on digitalocean to store my content but I don't like the idea of sending my content to my droplet via insecure FTP.

I have a little home server that I run off a crappy Dell and I was wondering if there was a way I could maybe

Send the FTP transfer to my local server (more secure because it will be behind firewalls/router) and then the little server will then send the received content to my droplet via SFTP

so like

Camera sends to > Little local server via FTP, which then sends the content via SFTP to > My Droplet

I hope this makes sense if anybody needs more clarification feel free to ask.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. What is your problem now ? You want to know how to configure sftp ?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like I just don't know what program to automate the middleman part where the SFTP uploads to the droplet

Comment: Why does your question say **how to secure a ftp transfer** when your question is **how to automate the SFTP uploads to droplet ?** ? What is running on your server ? Edit your question and mention the details more accurately so that your question gets better audience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I assume your Dell runs Windows OS.*

The easiest solution is to schedule a frequent regular synchronization from a drop folder of your local FTP server to the remote SFTP server.

For example, with WinSCP, just schedule a regular run of the following batch-file:

```
winscp.com /log=c:\path\sync.log /command ^
    "open sftp://user:password@example.com/" ^
    "synchronize remote c:\ftp\camera /path/camera" ^
    "exit"
```

For details, see WinSCP guide to:

- [Automating file transfers (or synchronization) to SFTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation)
- [Scheduling file transfers to SFTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule)

---

If you need to upload the pictures in a real time, you can run a continuous script instead with [`keepuptodate` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_keepuptodate).

---

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*